# Firebase grant custom claim on Client side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

As [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#defining_roles_via_an_http_request) says, there is a way to sets custom user claims on Client side doing an HTTP request.

I'm not using the admin portion since we just need to grant a custom claim after authentication if the user doesn't have it.

This is section is not working for me and it's throwing a `405` error code.

Can someone please help me with this?

The is a portion of the code I have in my Service file:

```
MobileAppNotificationService.prototype.checkClaim = function () {
    this.$window.firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(_.bind(function (idToken) {
        // Parse the ID token.
        var payload = JSON.parse(b64DecodeUnicode(idToken.split('.')[1]), DEFAULT_CHARSET);
        if (payload['admin']) {
            console.log("user has admin claim");
        } else {
            console.log("user DOES NOT has admin claim");
            this.grantAdminAccess(idToken);
        }
    }, this));
};

MobileAppNotificationService.prototype.grantAdminAccess = function (idToken) {
    this.$http.post(databaseUrl + '/setCustomClaims', {idToken: idToken}).then(function (data) {
        console.log("token saved!!!");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
};
```

Comment: The [documentation you link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#defining_roles_via_an_http_request) to requires both client-side and the server-side code. Did you implement both? If so, please share the minimal, exact code that you used.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added an example of the code I'm using to achieve the goal. The documentation explicitly says **Client side implementation (Javascript)**, so I guess there is no need to do the admin portion.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how it works. You'll need to implement both the client-side code and the server-side code that are in that documentation section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set custom claims with the the client SDKs.  That would be a massive security hole, where users could set their own permissions that would normally be controlled on the server.  Custom claims can only be set on the server with logic that cannot be manipulated by malicious clients.

Comment: We have an admin page in which we create the data for certain collection. That collection is restricted in Firebase by certain token so malicious user can not modify the data. Since only few user have access to editing the information and they previously have been logged in the admin app we need to grant them the claim so they can modify the information.

Comment: It seems like something is getting lost in translation here. Instead of describing what you've done, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).